# Get useragent in controller laravel 5 php

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.0. How do I get the user agent from $request in a controller ?

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $useragent = $request->userAgent; // ????
    return $useragent;
}
```

Comment: Just a note that in later versions of Laravel (5.4+), you can user `$request->userAgent()`.

Answer (score 51):

You can use either of following ways:

```
$ua = $request->server('HTTP_USER_AGENT');

$ua = $request->header('User-Agent');
```

Answer (score 6):

i think you can use this code

```
$user_agent = $request->header('User-Agent');
    $bname = 'Unknown';
    $platform = 'Unknown';

    //First get the platform?
    if (preg_match('/linux/i', $user_agent)) {
        $platform = 'linux';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $user_agent)) {
        $platform = 'mac';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $user_agent)) {
        $platform = 'windows';
    }

    echo $platform;

    echo "<br>";


    // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$user_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$user_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
        $ub = "MSIE";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$user_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
        $ub = "Firefox";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$user_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Google Chrome';
        $ub = "Chrome";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$user_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Apple Safari';
        $ub = "Safari";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$user_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Opera';
        $ub = "Opera";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$user_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Netscape';
        $ub = "Netscape";
    }

    echo $bname;
```

may be it is usefull this code . or another try laravel package 
 https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker
or 
https://github.com/jenssegers/agent

Answer (score 5):

Use this way it's work for me

```
echo Request::server('HTTP_USER_AGENT');
```

OR

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

Comment: `echo \Request::server('HTTP_USER_AGENT');`
For me work this Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

From laravel 5.4 you can do:

```php
$request->userAgent();
```

or

```php
request()->userAgent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Outside of controller can try:

```
$server = \Request::server();
echo $server['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```